# Why do the x and z values of CharacterController.velocity remain 0 when the CharacterController is in motion?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a [CharacterController](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController.html) component attached to a gameObject.

In the simplified version of my code below I'm assigning the x and z velocities of that controller to a Vector3.

```
    [SerializeField]
    private CharacterController controller;

    private Vector3 characterVelocity;
    private Vector3 horizontalVelocity;
    
    private float realSpeed;

    void Update()
    {
        
        characterVelocity = controller.velocity;
        horizontalVelocity = new Vector3(controller.velocity.x, 0, controller.velocity.z);
        realSpeed = horizontalVelocity.magnitude;

    }
```

I was using a script very similar to the example the Unity documentation used for `CharacterController.Move`. Using `CharacterController.Move` for both the horizontal movement and then again for jumping, as seen in said example, seems to nullify the x and z of `CharacterController.velocity`

When viewing the Inspector window in debug, the fields for the Vector3 "Horizontal Velocity" should display the velocities the CharacterController is moving along the the x and z planes. But those fields remain 0 when the player is moving as seen in this image:

[image]

When the character jumps the y velocity displays it's data as expected. Why would the x and z values not display any data?

Comment: Works for me with a movement script of `cc.Move(Time.deltaTime * (transform.forward * Input.GetAxis("Vertical") + transform.right * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")));` in `Update`. Voting to close until a [mre] is included in the question.

Comment: The only assumption I can make is that this part of the documentation for [`CharacterController.velocity`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController-velocity.html) was not read: 
**Note: The velocity returned is simply the difference in distance for the current timestep before and after a call to CharacterController.Move or CharacterController.SimpleMove. The velocity is relative because it won't track movements to the transform that happen outside of the CharacterController (e.g. character parented under another moving Transform, such as a moving vehicle).**

Comment: I had a very basic player setup, the CharacterController and transform were siblings of the same Player gameObject.

Comment: I was using a script very similar to the example the Unity documentation used for [CharacterController.Move](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController.Move.html). Using CharacterController.Move for both the horizontal movement and then again for jumping, as seen in said example, seems to nullify the x and z of CharacterController.velocity

Answer (score 3):

Combine your `CharacterController.Move` calls into one call to `CharacterController.Move`. As the documentation for [`CharacterController.velocity`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController-velocity.html) states (emphasis mine):

> The velocity returned is simply the difference in distance for the current timestep before and after **a call** to `CharacterController.Move` or `CharacterController.SimpleMove`.

That is to say, it only returns the difference before and after **one** call - not simply **any number of calls**.

Comment: Thanks Sir, you helped me a lot.

Comment: you can also move the call after you move the axis you want to check